# Why is the Problems view in Eclipse not showing all of my errors?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.4 Ganymede, and in my project there are several Java files that have compile errors. There's a red line at the error point when I open one of these files, but Eclipse doesn't show that there's a problem with the file at the project level.

Is there a property that needs to be set for that to happen? Why wouldn't all of my errors be shown in the Problems view?

Answer (score 1):

The project level shows the state of the classes *on disk* and not *in memory*.

In other words you can have plenty of compilation errors in your classes as you edit them, but the version on disk is not influenced until you save.

A quick way to synchronize is to use Ctrl-Alt-S which saves all edited files to disk.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set any specific property. In the menu, select `Windows -> Show View -> Problems` and it will open the problems view for you, showing all errors/warnings in your current workspace.

Comment: its not working, I am having error in 1000 classes but in problems it is hsowing only 2

Comment: 1000 classes? Did you ever do a project clean in eclipse?

Comment: As doonot suggested, try a clean build. Also, just to make sure you're synced, select the workspace node and hit F5 to force a refresh of all files in your solution-